# possible star train

Tags: amateur-observing

Over Pennsylvania cloudy night cleared long enough to star gaze, At first I thought shooting star but they kept going in an almost perfect row. Monday Apr 27,  approx. 8:30pm. about 15 or more white dots traveling across sky quickly. No blinking and bright enough to see with naked eye.  Please let me know what they were exactly.